# Check if string is in brackets { } but ignore "\{" and "\}"

Tags: java, regex

I want to check if given text is surrounded by curly brackets but also want to ignore them when they are "escaped". So I want to match `{Something}` but not `\{Something\}`...

What is the easiest way to do that?

Comment: the regex would be something like `[^\]\{(.*[^\])\}` (not a bracket, curly bracket, anything, not a bracket, curly bracket. What's inside the curly brackets is in the first group)

Comment: If you don't want to use a regex, you can check the string with the methods `.startsWith("{")` and `.endsWith("}")`.

Answer (score 0):

One could use negative look-behind, that is that no backslash was preceding. But if the backslash is a regular escape character, the `\\{` would be a backslash plus a brace.

For that case do:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\\\.|[^{\\\\])*\\{" // All upto open brace
        + "(\\\\.|[^}\\\\])*" // The sought, $2
        + "\\}"); // Closing brace

String s = "...";
Matcher m = pattern.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(2);
}
```

The pattern

```
(
    \\\\.             backslash followed by any char
|                     or
    [^{\\\\]          not one of: '{' or backslash
)
```